# Can't call function using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call a function using ajax, but it's not responding.

Here is the Code:

```
<p id="myElem" class="alert-danger" style="display:none"></p>

<button title="Remove" data-id="@item.Book.Book_id" class="Remove btn btn-group-sm red" style="float:initial">Remove</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.Remove').click(function () {

        var myId = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Remove", "ReadingNow")?Book_id=' + myId,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#myElem').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
                $('#myElem').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
            },
            failure: function (response) {

                alert("Failure");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

and here is the function :

```
 public class ReadingNowController : Controller
{
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Remove(int? Book_id)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var x = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            var IsExists = db.ReadingNow.Where(t => t.Book_Id == Book_id && t.User_Id == x).FirstOrDefault();

            if (IsExists != null)
            {

                db.ReadingNow.Remove(IsExists);
                int state = db.SaveChanges();
                if (state == 1)
                {
                    return Content("Book Removed From Your Reading Now List !");

                }
            }                

        }
        return Content("Error !");

    }
 }
```

Note: When I tried to call it directly it works, but when used ajax I got no result... How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ensure That jQuery Is Working**

Firstly, ensure that your jQuery code is working properly and is referenced. You'll need to include a reference to the library **prior** to calling any jQuery-related code :

```
<!-- Example Reference -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
          // Place your code here
    });
</script>
```

**If you want to perform a `GET`...**

You are specifying within your [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call that you are making a `POST` request via the `type` attribute, but your Controller Action is explicitly expecting a `GET` via the `[HttpGet]` attribute decorating your action.

You can resolve this by changing your `type` attribute from `POST` to `GET` (or you could remove it entirely as `GET` is the default):

```
type: "GET",
```

**If you want to perform a `POST`...**

Alternatively, if you want to actually perform a `POST`, then just keep your existing code and use the `[HttpPost]` attribute instead :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Remove(int? Book_id)
{
     // Code omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: Assuming you made one of the two changes that I proposed, it should work just fine. What does your current code look like after the changes?

Comment: I just changed the ajax type to GET ... that's confuse because when I call the method via url it's working and delete the item !

Comment: Try using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and seeing if any errors are present within the Network or Console tabs. It sounds as if your AJAX calls aren't working at all.

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint within your code? Is it hitting the Controller Action at all? What does the request look like when you click on your element to trigger the AJAX call?

Comment: Yes I tried it now , added a break point on $('.Remove').click and after I run the site and clicked , it did not pass there , so it's not going to the ajax after I click on button !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110569/discussion-between-f-msw-and-rion-williams).

Comment: Thanks , it was a bad mistake and you was very kind with me .. thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also call the `Controller` via `Ajax` by passing parameter(s) as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.Remove').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Remove", "ReadingNow")',
        data: { myId: $(this).data('id') /* add other additional parameters */ }, 
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#myElem').html(response).fadeIn('slow');
            $('#myElem').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow');
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("Failure");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i thing the problem is in this line:

> url: '@Url.Action("Remove", "ReadingNow")?Book_id=' + myId

dont use @Url.Action that is not the current syntax to use razor in JS (you need to use the  pseudo-element), just write the url 
["/ReadingNow/Remove?Book_id="+id]. that way you know for sure where the request will go and it easier to read.