# Back button causes current page postback. ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, back-button

I have a controller with 'Details' action and 'Edit' action.
I navigate to **Edit** using `View();` then a page with a partial view is rendered.

In the partial view there is a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateOrEdit", "Licenses", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "pure-form pure-form-aligned", id = "change", onsubmit = "process(this);" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="floatLeft width100per">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerId)

        <button onclick="goBack()" type="button" class="pure-button pure-button-primary newButton">Back</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="pure-button pure-button-primary newButton marginRight10" onclick="getModules(); setGuid('@Guid.NewGuid()');" />
        <div class="floatLeft pure-form">
```

**goBack() function:**

```
function goBack() {
    history.go(-1);
}
```

If I navigate to **Edit** and press the back button, everything's fine.
But if I press the **Save** button, form is being submitted and **CreateAndEdit** action is called - still OK.

The **CreateAndEdit** action uses:

```
RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = license.Id });
```

in order to navigate to **Details** page again.

Then, if I go to "Edit" again and then press **Back** -
**CreateAndEdit** action is called again - Not OK!

How can I always go back to "Details" page without calling **CreateAndEdit** when **Back** is pressed.

Comment: Define as anchor ( `<a` ) to go to defined url route instead of replying to browser history.

Comment: @ldanLevi You can try to use Ajax call as shown on [Can't call function using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922704/cant-call-function-using-ajax/36924707#36924707) and inform me if it is working for you.

Comment: @MuratYıldız It can work, but it's not the same as going back..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the cache for the page you don't want a user to be able to go back to due to form submission, etc.

You could try decorating the route with

```
[OutputCache(NoStore=true, Duration=0)]
```

I believe `[NoCache]` will also work as a decoration on your controller action.

Answer (score 1):

I think the behavior you are seeing is standard browser behavior. After you have submitted a form, if you then press the "Back" button of the browser (which is the same as `history.go(-1);`), the form will be resubmitted.

As a workaround, if the "CreateOrEdit" page is only accessible from the "Details" page, just redirect to the "Details" page directly instead of going through the browser history.

```
function goBack() {
    location.href = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Details", "Licenses",  new { id = Model.License.Id }))';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought of it too.. But I'm looking for another solution in order to maintain the history as it is.